# Vue.js HTML template compile-time checking

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, mvvm, asp.net-core, vue.js

We're in a process of migrating an existing ASP.NET Core Knockout.js / JS application to Vue.js / Typescript.

While the JS side gains the type-safety by the TS migration, we're having a hard time finding something that would do this checking for the HTML templates with vue bindings.

My idea (dream) would be something similar to what Razor does with it's typed models when having the precompile views option selected (when something's wrong with the bindings, it fails the build raising an error)

Is there any VS plugin, command line tool, or anything else that could provide this compile-time checking for Vue.js HTML templates?

EDIT:
To clarify better, let's say the template is

`<div id="root"><div v-html="myProp"></div></div>`

And very simplified Vue is like this

```
new Vue({el: '#root', data: {  myProp: 'my neat property value' }})
```

Now let's say someone makes a typo in the model property name so it's for example like this

`<div id="root"><div v-html="myPrapNotExisting"></div></div>`

If I did something similar in Razor, it would complain once the views are compiled and it would stop the build, however I haven't found anything similar for Vue (or knockout either)

So question is, is there a clientside MVVM framework, where templates could be compile-checked?

Comment: Can you provide an example of when and how you need type checking for templates? It's probably not possible because there is no type safety at runtime, but maybe there's a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I've added a lightweight sample with clarification what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but I'd suggest such a feature doesn't exist. Javascript objects can receive additional attributes during runtime, so accessing a non existing prop will just result in undefined, rather than an error. Vue will however tell you in the browser's console during runtime when you try to access a prop that doens't exist on the vue instance during mount. I know that's not what you're looking for, but it usually turns this type insecurity in templates into a non-issue, even though that might sound weird for someone with a strong .NET background at first.